# editing the last skype message using skype4com

Tags: c#, skype4com

i was trying to make it so if someone types !changeme it will enter 1 then change to 2

```
if (msg.Body.Equals("!changeme"))
                        {
                            msg.Chat.SendMessage("1");
                            msg.Body = "2";
```

and it doesn't seem to change 1 to 2

Comment: does the body of the condition get hit? put a breakpoint in it and check.

Comment: not familiar with skype api but most likely you should trigger an action like sendmessage again.

Comment: i found out what i did wrong it was just that i had to remove msg.chat.sendmessage("1");

and do 2 msg.body = ""; for it to work